# Is it possible to do inference using a pre-trained tensorflow model from inside cuda kernel?

Tags: c++, tensorflow, cuda, inference

I need to do inference using a tensorflow model from inside a cuda kernel. For that I will need DEVICE functions for inference that can be called from inside the cuda kernel. Did not find anything like that in tensorflow C++ API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm by no means an expert on Tensorflow. But consider that running GPU inference on a non-trivial network will generally involve multiple kernel calls. It would seem highly unlikely that the kind of API you're looking for exists. Even given that launching kernels from within other kernels would be possible in theory (e.g., using Dynamic Parallelism), the whole point of Tensorflow is to describe your computation at a level of abstraction far above anything to do with CUDA. You use Tensorflow to do the mapping to CUDA for you. Tensorflow is basically a kind of compiler that translates your computational graph into whatever it considers the best way of performing the computation described by the graph on the given target hardware. The details of this kind of mapping are highly target-specific and subject to change. Exposing any of this kind of stuff in a public API would seem to go against the very nature of what Tensorflow aims to be. Of course, Tensorflow is open source, so one can always just go look and figure out what exactly the device code generated by Tensorflow looks like and how it has to be invoked. However, the amount of effort required to do so is most likely prohibitive; and the whole thing would have to be expected to break with every new version…

Rather than ask the question of how to manually call the internals of a Tensorflow session, a more fruitful approach would seem to have Tensorflow call you instead. It would seem that, e.g., by [adding a custom operation](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/extend/op), you could have Tensorflow invoke your GPU code…